# Do not consider user timezone

Tags: javascript, angularjs, datetime

I'm in trouble with dates.

Note: I'm into Europe/Rome timezone.

I have the following date

```
....
new Date("2019-04-03T00:00:00+02:00")

 it returns:  Wed Apr 03 2019 00:00:00 GMT+0200 (Ora legale dell’Europa centrale)
....
```

If I change timezone (GMT -4) on my PC it returns, for example,

```
....
new Date("2019-04-03T00:00:00+02:00")
 it returns:  Tue Apr 02 2019 18:00:00 GMT-0400 (GMT-04:00)
....
```

What I want to do is to the date (2019-04-03T00:00:00+02:00) to a user's calendar without consider users timezone (even if it is in Canada I want to display on the user calendar Europe/Rome timezone.

Do you have any suggestions?

Thank you

Comment: The date shown in the console, "Tue Apr 02 2019 18:00:00 GMT-0400 (GMT-04:00)" is the exact same point in time as the date you passed in, "2019-04-03T00:00:00+02:00". If you want to display the date and time in the user's time zone, format the date in that time zone.

Comment: @ Heretic Monkey It is not a duplicate.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `moment.js` and `moment-timezone.js` to achieve the result.

```js
let ny = moment().tz("Europe/Rome").format();

console.log(ny);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.24.0/moment.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment-timezone/0.5.23/moment-timezone-with-data.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Generally, you want to use dates only as UTC, and convert them to whatever TZ you want when you display them.
[UTC in js](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/UTC)

[Moment](https://momentjs.com/timezone/docs/) is pretty good for these things,

```js
const moment = require("moment-timezone")
const now = moment.utc()
const nowButItsInYourTimezone = now.tz("Europe/Rome")
console.log(now.format()) // utc date
console.log(nowButItsInYourTimezone.format()) // gmt + 2, of the same date
```